# Is it switch weapons or switch weapon?

Tags: grammar

Is it switch weapons or switch weapon? I am not sure if we just use the plural in all cases, or there's a particular situation where you use the singular and a particular situation where you use the plural, but let's say you play a video game and you switch your pistol to a knife. Do you then say switch weapons or switch weapon?

Comment: Your question requires two readings because you do not write: to switch weapons, a verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 'switch' to mean'change one thing for another' then you would use the plural 'weapons'. There are two weapons (plural).

> switch
>   verb
>   B2 to change
>   suddenly or completely, especially from one thing to another, or to
>   exchange by replacing one person or thing with another:
>
> After the bank robbery, the gang switched cars (=
>   left one car and got into another).

[Switch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/switch)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.

If you are only specifically referring to a single weapon, and are using a pronoun or article to refer to it, then the singular is fine:

> ✔ I'm going to switch *my* weapon.
>   ✔ I'm going to switch *this* weapon.
>   ✔ I'm going to switch *the* weapon.

But you can also use the plural:

> ✔ I'm going to switch *my* weapons.
>   ✔ I'm going to switch *these* weapons.
>   ✔ I'm going to switch *the* weapons.

This may be referring to exchanging one weapon with another—or it may be referring to exchanging two or more weapons with the same number.

If you do not use a pronoun or an article, then only the plural works:

> ✔ I'm going to switch weapons.
>   ✘ I'm going to switch weapon.